# How to get Apache and PHP to talk

Tags: php, apache

I have successfully installed both Apache and php on my computer, Now I want to know how
to tell Apache what translator it needs to use when it is asked for a
.php file by users.

I tried adding the following code to the end of the httpd.conf file but afterward I was unable to start Apache service.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php5/"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php5/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

I get "the requested operation has failed!" error when I try to start apache service from apache service monitoring tool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Apache have you installed?

Comment: if you would like to run wamp on windows the easiest thing is to use the xampp installer https://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html. The System is ready in 5 Minutes. I would recommend to install a lamp system on debian in a virtual machine. It is portable and you dont have to deal with windows-specific issues.

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I want.

Comment: `PHPIniDir` mean the path to the php config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete your changes and then do almost the same thing but put the rows in the right place.
2. Search for the `LoadModule` statements in the httpd.conf-file. After the last `LoadModule` statement paste this:

   `LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"`
3. Search for `AddType` statements. After the last one paste this:

   `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`
4. Paste this at the very end of your httpd.conf-file:

   `PHPIniDir "c:/php"`

Change all instances of c:/php to c:/php5 if that is where you installed php.

Comment: cannot load c:/php5/php5apache2_4.dll into server. the specified procedure cannot be found

Comment: I didn't specify 2_4. I said "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"